# Does "defeat" trigger before/after battle abilities?

Tags: thunderstone-quest

Specifically in regards to Mawgarn's Axe which allows defeating a monster when moving through a dungeon area.

Unfortunately Defeat is not addressed within the Lexicon.

[image: Mawgarn's Axe - Choose a monster, for each level of the wielding hero, roll 1d6+1. If you roll lower than the Mosnter's HP, destroy this Hero. Otherwise, defeat it the next time this turn you move into of through its room.]

Answer (score 0):

Dungeon abilities are resolved before battles.  Thus, this would trigger prior to any Before Battle ability.